# get list of preinstalled packages debian 10

Tags: package, debian, apt

Is there a way to list all the packages that were preinstalled in debian 10 before I started installing packages myself, including dependencies etc ? And is there a way to re-initialize debian 10 by removing all these packages ?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

1. Find the oldest apt log file:

```
$ ls -la /var/log/apt/history.log*
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 19614 Dec 19 17:09 /var/log/apt/history.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  8570 Nov 29 17:05 /var/log/apt/history.log.1.gz
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  2573 Oct 23 11:09 /var/log/apt/history.log.2.gz
```

2. Find the first package you install manually (use `zcat` for `.gz` or `cat` otherwise):

```
$ zcat /var/log/apt/history.log.2.gz | grep '^Commandline: apt\(-get\)\? install' | head -1
Commandline: apt install gpm
```

It seems `gpm` is the first package I installed manually.

3. Get the list of all installed packages in chronological order:

```
$ zcat /var/log/dpkg.log.*.gz | cat - /var/log/dpkg.log | grep ' install ' | sort | awk '{print $4}'
```

Packages before your first manual package are the ones that were installed by Debian installer. Everything else is what you installed yourself.